# Define Rails routes with annotations like in Symfony

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symfony, routes

I'm currently learning Rails and it's awesome but I really like Symfony's routing system. In Symfony it is possible to define routes directly in Controller with annotations. For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
    }
}
```

This means that /blog/5 will route to PostController#showAction. I like this approach because routes are defined directly before your action method and, from my point of view, it makes more sense than defining everything in a single file.

Is there something similar for Rails?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing similar to this for Rails. With Rails, you must define the routes in `config/routes.rb` and have the controller actions separate. You could then put comments on the actions declaring what routes go to it, but most people don't do this.

If it *really* bothers you, you could use Sinatra which doesn't even have the concept of controllers. Instead, you define methods like this:

```
get '/' do
  "Hello world"
end
```

Any `GET` request going to `/` will show "Hello World" on the screen.

Sinatra is something that I would personally only use for featherweight applications, dipping into other things like Padrino or Rails for anything heavier.

Comment: Ironically, symfony1 lifted RaR's routing style almost exactly :)

Comment: It's pretty sad... Any idea of how to implement this feature? Is there annotation parsing class for Ruby or something like Reflection in PHP? I want to have this feature in Rails.

Comment: I can't see why this would be a good idea. With `routes.rb`, you get all your route definitions in one place. It sounds like what you're suggesting would scatter the route definitions all over the controllers. No thanks.

Comment: Yeah, and MVC is something bad because you can write everything in a single spaghetti.rb file.

Comment: That's not the same thing at all -- routing should IMHO be centralized. Also, Java-style @annotations are unidiomatic in Ruby -- the more Rubyish way of doing this would be class methods: `class PostsController; route 'blog'; end`, since Ruby class definitions are executable code.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you learn Rails idioms before you go trying to change them. If you think you can do better, please do so -- after you learn the usual idioms.

Comment: There is no difference for me how to define in-controller routes. I just want to have an opportunity to define global routing rules in routes.rb and individually configure it for each action in controller when I need to. From my point of view, this makes any framework more flexible and gives opportunities for better code organization in bigger projects. I'll try to make better when I have enough Ruby and Rails experience. Thank you for advice.

Comment: You can already define global routes in `routes.rb` -- that's what the catchall `:controller/:action` routes are -- and provide exceptions. I think you're trying to couple your routing (i.e. your UI) too closely to the controllers (i.e. the implementation).

Comment: Rules for a single action are always coupled with that action and doesn't matter where you place them, be it in routes.rb or at any other place. Global rules are regexps and group rules which are applied globally for many controllers and actions. I agree that these rules should be in routes.rb but when I want to set a rule for an individual action, I prefer it to be near this action because it makes much more sense. What if you have 1000 actions and need to set an individual rule for each one? Can you imagine how confusing the routes.rb file will be?

Comment: An application with 1000 actions has its own kinds of problems. This is when the routes file should probably be split up into smaller, more manageable chunks.

Comment: The point is, it's useless having this discussion. Rails does it a certain way and you cannot change that. If you don't like it, go use something else. Simple, really.

Comment: How stultifying. If something is a genuine improvement, it's worth seeing if it can be implemented. (I don't think the OP's idea is worth implementing, but that's another issue.)

Comment: @Marnen: Put, the thesaurus, down.

Comment: What thesaurus? I always talk like this. :D Now, did you have something to say about the content?

Comment: "stultifying" is not a word I knew of before you used it. Attempting to implement this within Rails would be madness.

Comment: Ryan: I think it would actually be pretty feasible to implement it in Rails. But I also think it's a terrible idea.